# Iterate a windows ascii text file, find all instances of {LINE2 1-9999} replace with {LINE2 "line number the code is on"}. Overwrite. Faster?

Tags: performance, powershell, replace, file-io, powershell-v5.1

This code works. I just want to see how much faster someone can make it work.

Backup your Windows 10 batch file in case something goes wrong.  Find all instances of string {LINE2 1-9999} and replace with {LINE2 "line number the code is on"}.  Overwrite, encoding as ASCII.

If _61.bat is:

```
TITLE %TIME%   NO "%zmyapps1%\*.*" ARCHIVE ATTRIBUTE   LINE2 1243
TITLE %TIME%   DOC/SET YQJ8   LINE2 1887
SET ztitle=%TIME%: WINFOLD   LINE2 2557
TITLE %TIME%   _*.* IN WINFOLD   LINE2 2597
TITLE %TIME%   %%ZDATE1%% YQJ25   LINE2 3672
TITLE %TIME%   FINISHED. PRESS ANY KEY TO SHUTDOWN ... LINE2 4922
```

Results:

```
TITLE %TIME%   NO "%zmyapps1%\*.*" ARCHIVE ATTRIBUTE   LINE2 1
TITLE %TIME%   DOC/SET YQJ8   LINE2 2
SET ztitle=%TIME%: WINFOLD   LINE2 3
TITLE %TIME%   _*.* IN WINFOLD   LINE2 4
TITLE %TIME%   %%ZDATE1%% YQJ25   LINE2 5
TITLE %TIME%   FINISHED. PRESS ANY KEY TO SHUTDOWN ... LINE2 6
```

Code:

```
Copy-Item $env:windir\_61.bat -d $env:temp\_61.bat
(gc $env:windir\_61.bat) | foreach -Begin {$lc = 1} -Process {
    $_ -replace "LINE2 \d*", "LINE2 $lc";
    $lc += 1
} | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $env:windir\_61.bat
```

I expect this to take less than 984 milliseconds. It takes 984 milliseconds.  Can you think of anything to speed it up?

Comment: Why is less than half a second for one-time-processing of a batch file a problem?

Comment: on my win7x64, ps5.1 setup, when i preload the input text and simply write to the screen ... your code takes 1.57 milliseconds. i have not tested with a file, but it seems unlikely to take 980+ milliseconds to copy, read & write the file. ///// how are you measuring the time involved?

Comment: Even after you changed the number from 375 ms to 984 ms (time dilatation?): why is less than a second for one-time-processing of a batch file a problem?

Comment: @somebadhat - you otta mention both of those bits on info in your post. [*grin*] as it stands, there is no way to know that your sample is a tiny piece of the too-slow code. ///// also, you likely ought to try using either `Measure_Command` or 1[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` so that others won't need to install 3rd party software to replicate your setup.

Comment: @somebadhat - ah! well ... you are not likely to get to-the-point help on this with incomplete info. [*grin*] in any case, i wish you the best of good luck on the project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **key to better performance in PowerShell code** (short of embedding C# code compiled on demand with `Add-Type`, which may or may not help) is to:

- **avoid use of cmdlets and the pipeline in general**,

  - especially invocation of a script block (`{...}`) for each pipeline input object, such as with `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object`
  - However, it isn't the pipeline *per se* that is to blame, it is the current *inefficient implementation* of these cmdlets - see [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982) - and there is a ***workaround* that noticeably improves pipeline performance**:

    ```
     # Faster alternative to:
     #   1..10 | ForEach-Object { $_ * 10 }
     1..10 | . { process { $_ * 10 } }

     # Faster alternative to:
     #   1..10 | Where-Object { $_ -gt 5 }
     1..10 | . { process { if ($_ -gt 5) { $_ } } }
    ```
- avoiding the pipeline requires **direct use of the .NET framework types** as an alternative to *cmdlets*.
- ***if feasible*, use `switch` statements for *array* or line-by-line *file* processing** - `switch` statements generally outperform `foreach` loops.

To be clear: **The pipeline and cmdlets offer clear benefits, so avoiding them should only be done if optimizing performance is a *must*.**

In your case, the following code, which combines the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) with **direct use of the .NET framework for file I/O** seems to offer the best performance - note that the input file is read into memory *as a whole*, as an array of lines, and a copy of that array with the modified lines is created before it is written back to the input file:

```
$file = "$env:temp\_61.bat" # must be a *full* path.
$lc = 0
$updatedLines = & { switch -Regex -File $file {
  '^(.*? LINE2 )\d+(.*)$' { $Matches[1] + ++$lc + $Matches[2] }
  default { ++$lc; $_ } # pass non-matching lines through
} }
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

Note:

- Enclosing the `switch` statement in `& { ... }` is an obscure performance optimization explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776311/45375).
- If case-*sensitive* matching is sufficient, as suggested by the sample input, you can improve performance *a little* more by adding the `-CaseSensitive` option to the `switch` command.

In my tests (see below), this provided a more than 4-fold performance improvement in Windows PowerShell relative to your command.

---

Here's a **performance comparison** via the [`Time-Command` function](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

The commands compared are:

- The `switch` command from above.
- A slightly streamlined version of your own command.
- A PowerShell *Core* v6.1+ alternative that uses the `-replace` operator with the array of lines as the LHS and a *scriptblock* as the replacement expression.

Instead of a 6-line sample file, a 6,000-line file is used.
100 runs are being averaged.
It's easy to adjust these parameters.

```
# Sample file content (6 lines)
$fileContent = @'
TITLE %TIME%   NO "%zmyapps1%\*.*" ARCHIVE ATTRIBUTE   LINE2 1243
TITLE %TIME%   DOC/SET YQJ8   LINE2 1887
SET ztitle=%TIME%: WINFOLD   LINE2 2557
TITLE %TIME%   _*.* IN WINFOLD   LINE2 2597
TITLE %TIME%   %%ZDATE1%% YQJ25   LINE2 3672
TITLE %TIME%   FINISHED. PRESS ANY KEY TO SHUTDOWN ... LINE2 4922

'@

# Determine the full path to a sample file.
# NOTE: Using the *full* path is a *must* when calling .NET methods, because
#       the latter generally don't see the same working dir. as PowerShell.
$file = "$PWD/test.bat"

# Create the sample file with the sample content repeated N times.
$repeatCount = 1000 # -> 6,000 lines
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $fileContent * $repeatCount)

# Warm up the file cache and count the lines.
$lineCount = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file).Count

# Define the commands to compare as an array of scriptblocks.
$commands =
  { # switch -Regex -File + [IO.File]::Read/WriteAllLines()
    $i = 0
    $updatedLines = & { switch -Regex -File $file {
      '^(.*? LINE2 )\d+(.*)$' { $Matches[1] + ++$i + $Matches[2] }
      default { ++$lc; $_ }
    } }
   [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $updatedLines, [text.encoding]::ASCII)
  },
  { # Get-Content + -replace + Set-Content
    (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object -Begin { $i = 1 } -Process {
      $_ -replace "LINE2 \d*", "LINE2 $i"
      ++$i
    } | Set-Content -Encoding Ascii $file
  }

# In PS Core v6.1+, also test -replace with a scriptblock operand.
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 6 -and $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor -ge 1) {
  $commands +=
    { # -replace with scriptblock + [IO.File]::Read/WriteAllLines()
      $i = 0
      [IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file,
        ([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file) -replace '(?<= LINE2 )\d+', { (++$i) }),
        [text.encoding]::ASCII
      )
    }
} else {
  Write-Warning "Skipping -replace-with-scriptblock command, because it isn't supported in this PS version."
}

# How many runs to average.
$runs = 100

Write-Verbose -vb "Averaging $runs runs with a $lineCount-line file of size $('{0:N2} MB' -f ((Get-Item $file).Length / 1mb))..."

Time-Command -Count $runs -ScriptBlock $commands
```

Here are sample results from my Windows 10 machine (the absolute timings aren't important, but hopefully the relative performance show in in the `Factor` column is somewhat representative); the PowerShell *Core* version used is v6.2.0-preview.4

```
# Windows 10, Windows PowerShell v5.1

WARNING: Skipping -replace-with-scriptblock command, because it isn't supported in this PS version.
VERBOSE: Averaging 100 runs with a 6000-line file of size 0.29 MB...

Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.108               # switch -Regex -File + [IO.File]::Read/WriteAllLines()...
4.22   0.455               # Get-Content + -replace + Set-Content...


# Windows 10, PowerShell Core v6.2.0-preview 4

VERBOSE: Averaging 100 runs with a 6000-line file of size 0.29 MB...

Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command
------ ------------------- -------
1.00   0.101               # switch -Regex -File + [IO.File]::Read/WriteAllLines()…
1.67   0.169               # -replace with scriptblock + [IO.File]::Read/WriteAllLines()…
4.98   0.503               # Get-Content + -replace + Set-Content…
```