# Powershell slow searching within imported csv

Tags: powershell, object, search

I am using a csv file to load a table-like object and then search this for existing items. 
With only 2000 items, a computer running on a I5 CPU takes 4 seconds perform search using `where` on 2 columns. Wondering what I am doing wrong:

```
$uploadedRecordings = import-csv -path $ArchiveUploadedFilesInGoogleDrive
...[some other code]
if($uploadedRecordings | where { $_.Name -eq $filename -and $_.Size -eq $item.file_size}){
               Write-Host "[Already downloaded] Skipping....
}
```

Where `$item` (sample):

```
id              : f5b693
meeting_id      : uT4dfhghd==
recording_start : 2020-03-25T16:01:31Z
recording_end   : 2020-03-25T18:14:36Z
file_type       : M4A
file_size       : 54332420
play_url        : https://myurl
download_url    : https://otherurl
status          : completed
recording_type  : audio_only
```

and `$filename = "Meeting - 2020-04-20 -- 09.29.59.mp4"`

Comment: Please show what you've assigned to `$filename` and `$item` as well

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: So `$item` is an array of items like the sample you posted?

Comment: `$item` has only element, values will change in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell offers great features, far beyond what traditional shells offer, but one thing it is not: a speed demon.

PowerShell's object-oriented pipeline is a wonderful tool, but it can be slow.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54753717/45375) summarizes performance recommendations; in the case at hand, you can speed up your command by avoiding the pipeline in favor of the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where):

```
if ($uploadedRecordings.Where({ 
  $_.Size -eq $item.file_size -and $_.Name -eq $filename 
})) {
  Write-Host "[Already downloaded] Skipping..."
}
```

Also note how I've swapped the `-and` operands in favor of comparing file sizes first, to take advantage of short-circuiting; after all, files being exactly identical in size is less common than their having the same name.

You *may* be able to speed things up further a bit by caching `$item.file_size` in an auxiliary variable, though my hunch is that that won't make much of a difference in practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There's a slight gain with your solution (in your sample it misses the second closed parenthesis as for the `if` statement). Does it makes any sense to bother changing the CSV to a hastable? Searches seem to be much faster: https://www.get-blog.com/?p=122 but how should I change the code, as the CSV has 3 columns filename, date, size

Comment: @Riccardo `Import-Csv` doesn't directly allow you to import the file as a hashtable. How, exactly, are you processing the rows? One way to speed things up would be to use plain-text processing via `switch` statement, but that is more cumbersome.

Comment: Further investigation shows that your suggested code runs much better than it was! Thanks